# How to change the minSdkVersion only when running tests

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-testing

I have an android studio project with minSdkVersion set to 14 in both AndroidManifest.xml and in build.gradle

Now I want to write some automated tests so I added some more dependences in build.gradle. One of them is:
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'

When I try to run the tests I get:

Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugTestManifest'. java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" to force usage

I changed my manifest file to: , but this didn't help.

If I change build.gradle to minSdkVersion 18, then it works. But I don't want to change the minSdkVersion of my app just because of the test libraries.

Is there a way to configure build.gradle to use minSdkVersion 18 when I run the automated tests, but keep minSdkVersion 14 for the app?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

1. Create two flavours:

   - appConfig : it is empty so it inherits all from defaultConfig
   - testConfig : it declares minSdkVersion 18.
2. Add the dependency for uiautomator for the testConfig only.

Below is the excerpt from my build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        appConfig {
        }
        testConfig {
            minSdkVersion 18
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
...
    testConfigCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Still showing error when appConfigDebug is chosen.